# How to develop a page which displays data from more than one content type/table

Tags: views

how do I develop a view/page which displays the data like below.

I have the Image, blogger name ( this is my join field) , profile photo and details as one content type(table) 
and Blogs are in different content type (table). Blogs content type has also blogger name.

I'm newbie to drupal and we are using Drupal 7.

Bloggers are not going thru user registration process and as admin's we enter the blogger details as bloggers content type (for those who enter more blogs).

Any help/hints on how to accomplish this

[image]

Comment: If all data you want to display take from different different content type. you can create a view by selecting the view type all and filter the content type as per your requirement.

Comment: The Views module is likely what you're looking for to simplify this.  You can easily gather the data you need into a single query and then them it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the commenters to your question, use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. Here's some [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/views) to get you started.

In general, it is an enhanced query/list/menu builder, with which you can build most of your site's general pages, blocks and lists.

You can join multiple tables (or content types) in any way Drupal's structure lets you, and output the results as

- a table of columns and rows (one record per row),
- a grid with multi records per row,
- short lists used to make menus,
- and so much more.

Views should be in any newb tool chest of modules (opinion). It's invaluable for examining your site content, and in learning Drupal's content relationships (after you get beyond it's learning curve). It's now even in Drupal 8 core.